# Any collaborative tool/website to localize an Android app?

Tags: android, localization, collaboration

My open source Android application has internationalization done the Android way, with strings.xml files.

The community has many people from many countries, and they are willing to contribute/improve translations using a collaborative website.

There is [Launchpad](https://translations.launchpad.net) but it only supports the gettext format so we would have to use scripts, not very convenient.

What website is convenient for translating open source Android applications?
Anybody must be able to start contributing without any sort of prior approval.

Comment: I am also searching for the **perfect** Android translation service: free for open source projects, imports the string resources from the projects VCS (git/hg/...) automatically if something changes on the master file(s), allows me to blacklist some strings (because they are preferences, not visible to the end-user), does batch commit or at least provides a clone of my VCS where I can pull the translation commits.
But none of the ones in the answers does meet these criteria. Looks like I am asking for too much :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One tool was not yet listed so far - [Weblate](http://weblate.org/). It has native support for Android string resources and is already used for several apps (for example [OsmAnd](http://www.osmand.net/)). Though it requires you to use distributed version control system (preferably Git).

Comment: Looks great! Git integration is a killer feature, and the platform being Open Source itself makes it very attractive. I will be sure to use it for my next project!

Answer (score 17):

I opted for [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/). It allows the admin to upload the XML files, and then anyone can translate to any language.

Translated files can be downloaded in a ZIP archive.

It is free for Open Source projects.

The UI used to be really slow, but it has got better recently.

Comment: And overloaded they are. Their website is excruciatingly slow. I wonder if there are other websites that do this, that are also specifically tailored to iOS projects.

Comment: 2012 update: Crowdin is much faster recently!

Comment: Transifex and Get Localization are really good alternatives, by the way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15993821/89818

Comment: @MarcoW. GetLocalization has already been proposed, see below. Please propose Transifex as a separate answer, thanks!

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul, it seems you are related to this product, is that right?

Comment: @mnieber: I am not related to this product. I use Crowdin for two of my apps: https://github.com/ankidroid and http://CmisSync.com and when there is a bug on their website I tell them, that's all.

Answer (score 11):

I've written a tool to convert between Android XML resources and .po files:

http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2010/04/08/android2po-managing-android-translations/
 http://github.com/miracle2k/android2po

I'm using this myself with Pootle, and it works well enough, though I'm not really all that happy with the Pootle UI. Crowdin is in fact much better in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for android2po! We use it for one of our research projects along with Pootle. I'm curious if you think it would still add value if Pootle started supporting Android String resources natively. Are there other tools that handle PO files that would benefit Android development?

Comment: Sure, native support in the translation tool you're using would be a superior solution. For example, string attributes like "formatted=False" laborious need to be maintained via .po comments   (and in fact a2po doesn't currently to this).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a small tool I've developed: http://www.lokaligo.com/.

Probably not perfect, but for me, for now does the job.

Comment: +1 The "open projects, where anybody can join as a translator" feature is what I am looking for. Something is not clear to me: when you say "Free up to 100 resources and during the beta period", do you mean that the "100 free resources" offer will switch to a paid plan at the end of the beta period?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Even when I will implement a payment system, first 100 resources will stay free. Ideally, I would like that anybody could use that tool for small/personal/open-source projects.

Comment: Thanks! The new wording `Free during beta period - afterwards free up to 100 resources` is much clearer to me indeed :-)

Comment: +1 Great platform, started using it yesterday! Although I have some small improvements for the site!

Comment: Looks really good, but there's no proper support of strings that contain CDATA tags... That is very unfortunate!

Answer (score 5):

Localize your apps and content more easily – Android Resource (.xml) formats now supported in Translator Toolkit [1]
http://translate.google.com/toolkit

[1] http://googledevelopers.blogspot.nl/2012/03/localize-your-apps-and-content-more.html

Comment: I have tried it, but don't find it very convenient. It seems that for each new language I have to upload all XML files again. And I have to share the document with specific people, it can not be open to the public. So, if a cool Hungarian guy wants to contribute a bit, he has to ask me to upload all XML files to allow Hungarian translations, then I have to send him an invite. That's really a pain. Compare that with Crowdin where all languages are available by default, and anyone can start contributing without asking for permission.

Answer (score 5):

See Get Localization http://www.getlocalization.com, it integrates with Eclipse.

Comment: +1 Seems to be free for public projects, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

[Amanuens.com](http://www.amanuens.com) has also support for android builtin, is free in 2011, syncs with your repo, but personally I dislike the editor.

Comment: +1 Batch sync with Git is a wonderful feature! It seems geared towards non-open software though: admin must assign translations to existing translators, anonymous can't see the project files. It would be great if they had an option for open source project, with Wikipedia-style liberal permissions.

Comment: And this service is discontinued as of 31 july 2012.

Answer (score 2):

[Pootle](http://pootle.translatehouse.org) is a great localisation platform with many features and support for many [formats](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/formats/index.html). The upcoming version supports even more formats and adding new formats is very simple.

Comment: Does Pootle support android natively now?

Comment: not yet, after this list: [Supported Formats](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/formats)

Answer (score 2):

[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) is a really good tool for collaborative translation. It offers paid plans, a free demo for 15 days and is free for open source projects.

Comment: +1 Transifex says it offers free plans for open source projects "without limitations in the word count".

Answer (score 2):

I use [Androglot.com](http://www.androglot.com), its quite early stage but promising, free and open to anyone, supports Android string.xml files (and string-array) without restrictions...

Comment: +1 Interesting approach: "Each Developer is also a Translator, and the more translations you make, the more you get". This is life-changing to kickstart an app in a country where it has no community yet (ex:Korea). I hope non-developer translators can also help and redirect their points to their favorite app (maybe starting from zero points), but it is not clear whether this is possible or not.

Comment: This really is a good idea, but the UI is kinda ugly, and buggy. I'm getting 404s and I'm unable to upload two XML files for a single language. But this looks really promising, I'll keep an eye on it!

Answer (score 1):

I found [MyGengo's String](http://mygengo.com/string/), which has native support for Android string resources. They're still a little buggy, but they have a slick interface. They're free for public projects.

Are there any others that have sprung up since last year? (please post as a new answer, not a comment to this answer)

Comment: This service discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

I've started using android2po with a [Drupal-based translation tool](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2010-may-05/using-drupal-collaborative-software-translation-tool).

Comment: I've switched to Weblate, which is very nice, but has crippling bugs with Android string resources for now (incorrect escapes, lack of support for string-arrays).

Comment: Weblate is mostly fixed now, but has some quirks. I'd admirably maintained though.

Comment: A new options has emerged, seemingly free for all projects and well thought-out: http://www.oneskyapp.com/

Comment: Because I couldn't find a translation website that did what I was looking for, I have developed an own solution that also supports screenshots for translations (so that the volunteers can see the context where the text is used). It can currently be used for free [here](https://calengoo.de/TranslationServer). It is planned to add further features in the future but it should already work fine. Just contact me if you have any problems with it.