# Translate easily xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, compare, translation

I want to translate app in Android (strings.xml and array.xml), but I don't know how to compare the file to check the untranslate strings. So I search a software to make this.

Thank you!

Comment: you can check my tool here https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidresourcetranslator/

Comment: The tool is not working @Khayam

Comment: Bing might have changed there API or the way it is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to translate between various languages? If yes, [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) is what you might be searching for.

Comment: I found my anwser, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Try [Google Translator Toolkit](http://translate.google.com/toolkit/) to easily transate your app.

Comment: This will show a page asking for $46 per language.  Click "No Thanks"  I'll translate myself or invite friends for help.  This will send you to the free version

Comment: That webpage is not available)

Answer (score 2):

try this thread
[Any collaborative tool/website to localize an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520891/any-collaborative-tool-website-to-localize-an-android-app)
basically what proved to work is the android2po tool and then you can use your favourite .po editor