# Localization of apps on Android

Tags: android, localization

I was wonderering if there is a way to do simple string localization on Android so that the text can be given to a translation service without beeing too worried about them making mistakes in any code.

On iPhone there this is really easy with localizedStrings where I just write

```
"string in lang1" = "string in lang2".
```

On Android I currently do it the "normal" way with string ressources

```
  <string name="alert_OK">string in lang1</string>
```

Then the resulted translation file would look like:

```
  <string name="alert_OK">string in lang2</string>
```

But it's obvious that one hesitates to give a file in this format to any non-programmer.

Is there another alternative which is less errorprone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's special software for localization Android resources: [look here](http://yehongmei.narod.ru/)

Application actually extracts resources from XML file and make them more comfortable for translators to work. Never tried, but guys who used reports that it's neat.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer describing (collaborative) translation editing tools:

[Any collaborative tool/website to localize an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520891/any-collaborative-tool-website-to-localize-an-android-app)