# Translating XML strings for Android

Tags: android

I have some customers who have volunteered to translate my app's strings into their native languages. Of course they will not be using the Eclipse Android environment to do this, so what Windows-based tool/editor would be appropriate for them to use to work on the XML files that I send them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) editor for manipulate xmls, it is very easy to use this application.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try this out, then recommend it to my "volunteers".

Answer (score 5):

I've been following your strategy as well for quite some time. Whenever a volunteer wanted to translate the app, he got the XML file containing all the strings, translated it and sent it back to me.

But people who are not very familiar with computers tend to fail at that task: I often received the XML files back as Microsoft Word documents (.doc) or they translated the XML keys (which become the strings' IDs later) as well.

Therefore I recommend you to use some convenient tool for collaborative translation such as [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/), [crowdin](https://crowdin.com/) or [Get Localization](http://www.getlocalization.com/).

You can even use a small website I've set up mainly for myself that offers [Android translation](http://localize.li/) as well if you don't want to pay for those services. It's not beautiful, but it should do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an automatic translation tool. I had created one and is available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidresourcetranslator/).

Answer (score 0):

I also created an android string translator and prepared a short  video to explain how it works. This video can be opened at the indicated link from screencast. The link  links to the location of the Excel file that runs the translation code. The file is code signed, free and ready to go.
https://app.screencast.com/3175zvrfOg6dZ?conversation=DJjUGfR9NPJLPAxLv3Hg5F&tab=Details
`
In Android Studio I developed nine hundred key string pairs relevant to my application.
Android encapsulates each of these strings in a particular format.
Android provides for different languages by retaining a key value and a translated value as part of a unique string. A list of strings needs to exist in the app, for all required languages.
The Program translated 907 strings into twelve different languages. These languages are English, Arabic, Bengali, Chinese, French, Hindi, Indonesian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish. The total count of strings is close to 11000.
This would be a formidable task if done manually and so a computerized process makes it easier.
These languages are now all set up in my android application.
An android user can choose one of eleven languages to use the application. The translations are based on the visual basic routines created in Microsoft excel. The program backcheck the translated words back into English. The translations do not always carry the intending meaning when backchecked.
For example, when the program translates the English string, False, into Bengali, the program produces a Bengali string. When the program backchecks the Bengali string to English, the result is the English word, lie. There is a connection to the original meaning.
I concluded that the program would be useable in another language. The user would need to pay attention these variations in nuance.